# Google Spreadsheet - Index Match - Match to Horizontal Column Names

Tags: google-sheets

I'm struggling to understand Index, Match and I am wondering if perhaps it is not appropriate for what I am trying to do.

I have several columns of pay codes with pay values in them.  I want another column that combines all their values with another sheet that contains a list of the codes and descriptions.

I've tried to get index match to work for me, but I think because I am trying to match the horizontal column names that is what is messing me up.

Can anyone help me understand Index Match where I need to match a column of data to a row of column names and then put only the non-blank cells from the range in a special format?

Here is my sheet sample. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/175HbwmFf2Z_S_5Q-w6k6DOYC2MXenTefxbKy_y57sfA/edit?usp=sharing

Any help is appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: the link isn't working

Comment: It appears to be working, perhaps refresh the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try (in F2)

```
=trim(join(,ArrayFormula(if(transpose($A2:$E2)<>"", transpose($A$1:$E$1&" "&VLOOKUP($A$1:$E$1, Pay_Codes!$A$1:$B, 2, 0)&" - "&$A2:$E2&char(10)),))))
```

and drag down..

Comment: Wow, ok so no Index Match needed, vlookup does it then? Thank you so much!